# conditionally add formGroup to another formGroup angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to add a formGroup to my overall form conditional on a specific field being of a certain type in my case. My function to add this formGroup looks like this:

```
  initSocial() {
      const group = <FormGroup>this.cardForm;
        group.addControl(
          'social': this._fb.group({
            'fb': new FormControl(this.currentCard.social.fb),
            'yt': new FormControl(this.currentCard.social.yt),
            'ig': new FormControl(this.currentCard.social.ig),
            'tw': new FormControl(this.currentCard.social.tw),
          })
        )
  }
```

Right now I am getting a typescript error under the colon after 'social' saying a ',' is expected. I haven't been able to test this to see if addControl() will even work.

My function to fire initSocial is in ngOnInit and looks like this:

```
      if(this.currentCard.cardType === "brand"){
        this.initSocial();
      }
```

Any help/tips/suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: you are missing `{}` around `'social'`. Please don't post "why this code doesn't work" kind of questions.

Comment: that could also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55334283/reactive-forms-how-to-add-new-formgroup-or-formarray-into-an-existing-formgroup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`addControl()` function looks like:

```
/**
 * Add a control to this group.
 * @param {?} name
 * @param {?} control
 * @return {?}
 */
FormGroup.prototype.addControl = function (name, control) {
    this.registerControl(name, control);
    this.updateValueAndValidity();
    this._onCollectionChange();
};
```

and expects 2 arguments: *name* and *control*, separated by comma.
So, just try to replace semicolon (*:*) after 'social' with comma (*,*):

```
group.addControl('social', this._fb.group({
  fb: this.currentCard.social.fb,
  yt: this.currentCard.social.yt,
  ig: this.currentCard.social.ig,
  tw: this.currentCard.social.tw,
}))
```

also, you do not need `new FormControl(DEFAULT_VALUE)`, form builder does it already

Comment: Geez! That was painfully simple. This got the function working properly. Thank You @Andriy!