# Reactive Forms: How to add new FormGroup or FormArray into an existing FormGroup at a later point in time in Angular till v14

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

In the other examples at StackOverflow there are many questions about using FormGroups in FormArrays. But my question is the opposite.

FormArrays have a push method, that makes many things possible. FormGroups have indeed an addControl method for adding simple FormControls. AFAIK FormGroups do not have `addFormArray` or `addFormGroup` method. Therefore I need your help.

Following situation:

```js
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  id: this.fb.control([this.book.id]),
  // or short form `id: [this.book.id],`
});
```

Adding a simple control at a later point in time is easy:

```js
this.myForm.addControl('isbn', this.fb.control(this.book.isbn));
```

But what about adding FormArrays and FormGroups into an existing FormGroup? For instance, I would like to use the following array and object for this purpose:

```js
const authors  = ['George Michael', 'Aretha Franklin'];
const metaData = { description : 'Great Book', publication: 2019}
```

I would like to add `authorsArray` or `metaData` only then if they are existing. That's the reason, why I want to add them at a later time.

p.s. Please ignore the validation rules.

Comment: Hello. You add your FormGroups and FormArrays just you added your FormControl.

Comment: `registerControl` might work as well. Both of these functions take an AbstractControl as an arguement. FormGroup  extends AbstractControl so this should work for FormGroups as well.

Comment: You might want look at this answer of mine. Hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666593/add-item-in-dynamic-reactive-form-in-angular/49667898#49667898

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`FormGroup` [addControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl) method accepts `AbstractControl` as parameter which can be either a `FormControl` or a `FormArray` or another `FormGroup` as they all extend `AbstractControl`.

```js
class FormGroup extends AbstractControl {}

class FormControl extends AbstractControl {}

class FormArray extends AbstractControl {}
```

[FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) can help you building such controls with `array()` and `group()` methods:

```js
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  id: this.fb.control([this.book.id]),
  authors: this.fb.array(['George Michael', 'Aretha Franklin']),
  metaData: this.fb.group({ description : 'Great Book', publication: 2019})
});
```

You still can use the factory afterwards to build the controls you need (no matter what kind of control it is):

```js
this.myForm.addControl('authors',
                       this.fb.array(['George Michael', 'Aretha Franklin']))
this.myForm.addControl('metaData',
                       this.fb.group({description: 'Great Book', publication: 2019}))
```

Comment: thank you, how would you add authors and metaData in the case above?

Comment: `this.myForm.addControl('isbn', this.fb.group({ authors  : [], metaData: ''}));` - have not tested but that might work

Comment: Edited accordingly

Comment: I supouse you can use `this.myForm.addControl('authors',new FormArray(authors .map(x=>new FormControl(x))))`

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer thank you but: at a later point in time, not in time of creation of the whole group.

Comment: you still can use the form builder with the addControl method.

Comment: Or, if you want a empty formArray `this.myForm.addControl('authors',new FormArray([]))`

Comment: @Eliseo thank you, would you use `authors` in the example above?

Comment: @GrégoryElhaimer you mean that one: `this.myForm.addControl('authors', this.fb.array(['George Michael', 'Aretha Franklin']));`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass the `FormArray` instead of a `FormControl`.

`this.form.addControl('arr',this.fb.array([]));`

### Edit: To use existing value

To use the value from the `authors` array, use this:

```
authors.forEach(author => {
  (<FormArray>this.form.controls.arr).push(new FormControl(author));
});
```

### OR

`this.myForm.addControl('authors', this.fb.array(['George Michael', 'Aretha Franklin']))`